# How to wait for a user click in page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Many times I would like to pause a Selenium test while I take a look at the page. Is there a way in `Selenium` to wait until user clicks in page or until user hits a key on the keyboard?

Something like:

`wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.UserClickElement(locator));`

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in your debugger. Otherwise this kinda defeats the purpose of automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't a legitimate use of Selenium (WebDriver). It's a web-driving tool, not a development environment.

However, you're just looking for something to help **you** write and debug your test cases, which is fair enough.

As @SiKing said, you could just set a breakpoint in your debugger.

However, a more low-tech way is simply to add a wait to your code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);  // 30 seconds
```

that gives you just enough time to check the page before execution restarts. Once you've fixed your problem you can remove the wait and move on.

Waiting for clicks or keypresses would be neat, but you would have to implement that entirely from scratch in your own C# code, and by the time you've made that usable throughout all your tests you'd be well on the way to creating your own test framework.

If you concentrate on making your tests **stable**, then although the `Sleep` approach would make development a little slow, you shouldn't have to spend time developing debugging capabilities.